# Autodesk's adsk-icon-* classes

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

Does anybody know if there is a documentation about the different Autodesk adsk-icon-* classes they are using for the toolbar in the Forge-Viewer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the only (publicly accessible) official documentation re toolbar is [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v6/reference/javascript/toolbar/) and [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v6/tutorials/toolbar-button/).

However if you dig into the [full stylesheet](https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/style.css?v=v6.0) and start from line 1265 (`[class^="adsk-icon-"]`...) you will have a pretty clear idea on how to work with these classes and do go and examine the font (`adsk-viewing`) data string using your browser console to further understand how the typesetting works. You can download this font face by simply going to the Network tab of your browser’s Developer Tools and double click on the data URI that starts with `data application/font`.